# operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
iarray<T>& operator =    (iarray<T>& v)
```

Why the return type is `iarray<T>&`  not `iarray<T>` ?

**UPDATE**

Can someone elaborate in great detail why `iarray<T> const &v` ?

Comment: Note that it should normally be `iarray<T> &operator=(iarray<T> const &v)`;

Comment: Can you elaborate why `iarray<T> const &v`?

Comment: @Alan: so the value of a temporary (which can't be bound to a non-const ref) can be assigned.

Answer (score 8):

Because you don't want to return a copy of the array just for the sake of chaining. Returning a reference is a better option as it doesn't result in a copy being constructed.

Answer (score 3):

Because then you can chain them *efficiently*, eg.

```
a = b = c;
```

See the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references).

Answer (score 0):

> Why the return type is iarray& not iarray ?

Because the result of an assignment is a reference to what just got assigned. For example, the result of `a = b` should be a reference to `a` so you can chain them together like in `c = a = b;` which is effectively `a = b; c = a;`. (Yes, people like doing this on rare occasions; no, I don't know why it's such a hardship to break it into two lines.)  Thus your code should look like:

```
iarray<T>& iarray<T>::operator = (const iarray<T>& v)
{
   // ... copy `v`'s state over this object's ...

   return *this;
}
```

> Can someone elaborate in great detail why iarray const &v ?

Because an assignment operation has no business changing the right-hand side; it is unexpected behavior.  If you have some funky thing in your object that needs to change, like a reference count, then you should prefer declaring that one part `mutable` over disallowing `const` right-hand side expressions.  You can pass a non-`const` value in for a `const` parameter, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: I think chaining also works if the return type is `iarray<T>`,dont you?

Comment: It results in the creation and destruction of an unnecessary temporary object.  So return a reference.  Make it a `const` reference if it makes you feel better.